# Sqoop export -D oracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp=false working only in--connection-param-file ora.properties

Tags: hdfs, sqoop

> sqoop export -D oracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp=false --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xxx:1521/BDWDEV4 --username xxx --password xxx --table TW5T0 --export-dir '/data/raw/oltp/cogen/oraclexport/TW5T0/2015-08-18' -m 8 --input-fields-terminated-by '\001' --lines-terminated-by '\n' --input-escaped-by '\"' --input-optionally-enclosed-by '\"'

The effect of **oracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp=false** is not working

But the same thing:

> sqoop export --connection-param-file ora.properties --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xxx:1521/BDWDEV4 --username xxx --password xxx --table TW5T0 --export-dir '/data/raw/oltp/cogen/oraclexport/TW5T0/2015-08-18' -m 8 --input-fields-terminated-by '\001' --lines-terminated-by '\n' --input-escaped-by '\"' --input-optionally-enclosed-by '\"'

where "ora.properties" contains **oracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp=false**, works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just the blank space between `-D` and `oracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp=false` ?

HTH
  Thorsten